# Help with simple algebra equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing some math to prepare for a test, and $$\left(\frac{a^2}{b^{-1}}\right)^{-3}\cdot\left(\frac{(2b)^3}{a^{-3}}\right)$$ is apparently $8a^{-3}$. When I try to solve it the closest I get is $7a^{-3}$. After multiplying the upper case numbers and dissolving the parentheses I am left with: $$\frac{a^{-6}\cdot6b^{3}}{b^3\cdot a^{-3}}$$ I get that when I cross out the $b^3$'s I am left with $1$ since $b^0 = 1$, but that is just $6+1$. With the a's left I get $7a^{-3}$. Could anyone tell me what I'm missing, how does it turn to $8a^{-3}$?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the first mistake is that $$(2b)^3=2^3b^3=8b^3$$ and not $6b^3$ as you have it. Moreover, when you simplify the $b^3$ you have to multiply with $1$ and **not** add $1$. This will give you the required result.

Comment: I also got to thank you for the answer, but I a got a follow-up question too. What is the reason for multiplying instead of adding? I'm probably missing something very obvious, but I'll try to learn as much as possible while I'm here.

Comment: @Tony Tony, look. You just eliminate from above and below which was previously multiplied, not added. So, why should you add him now?

Comment: Haha, its true when you say it since it previously was 8*b^3, but since it became 1, you just multiply with 1 instead of b^3. Better to be 100% sure than less. Thanks for being patient with me, I think I'm prepared for future equations like this now!

Comment: @Tony haha, yes you are! Good luck with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left(\frac{a^2}{b^{-1}}\right)^{-3} \frac{(2b)^3}{a^{-3}}
$$ is what is being asked. The powers are multiplied when you work it out, so it becomes

$$\frac{a^{-6}}{b^3}\frac{8b^3}{a^{-3}}$$

The 8 comes from $2^3$. Then the two $b^3$ cancels out against each other, and there is only $a^{-3}$ left from the power of a. So the final results yields

$$8a^{-3}$$

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer it made me nuts, I multiplied 2 with 3 instead of seeing it as 2^3. And could I ask another question as a follow-up? In my text book is says that b^3-^3= b^0 which is 1. But   how does b^3/b^3 work? A normal equation like 7/7 is 1, but why is b^3/b^3 equal 0?

Sorry for the formatting, don't know how you do it properly.

Comment: because $b^3 / b^3$ is dividing something with itself. That is by default 1 (except for zero). $b^3 * b^{-3} = 1$ because $b^{-3} = 1 / b^3$ which equals to the first equation I wrote in this comment